# Laravel Allow (') apostrophe in regex

Tags: regex, laravel

I am trying to allow some symbols in regex like ( ) . and ' , but only ' is not working

here is the code :

`'address'  => "required|max:255|regex:/^[\pL\s\-.,0-9()\']+$/u"`

Comment: It should work. Try `/^[\pL\s.,0-9()\\x27-]+$/u`, too.

Comment: still not working!

Comment: And what is the input? Please add all relevant code.

Comment: I am next to convinced you have `htmlentities` somewhere that modifies your input string. Please make sure you test the regex against **plain text**.